How to resolve S3.Client.upload_fileobj resulting in ssl.SSLCertVerificationError - certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate?
We are running Python code on a Docker Image (--platform=linux/amd64) that is resulting in an SSL error - seemingly some sort of SSL certificate is failing when trying to upload a JSON file to an S3 object via boto3. The exact same code is working in our local development environments, but when trying the same code on a Docker Image, we receive the following error:

ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/gg-9TtSrW0h-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/gg-9TtSrW0h-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1104, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1375, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)



The code:
class S3Connection(Connection):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._open()
        return self

    def __exit__(
        self,
        exception_type: str,
        exception_value: str,
        exception_traceback: str,
    ):
        self._close()

    def _open(self):
        self.sts_client = get_sts_client()
        self.credentials_response = self.sts_client.assume_role(
            RoleArn=HIPPOGRIFF_ROLE,
            RoleSessionName=self.session_name,
        )
        self.session = get_session(
            self.credentials_response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
            self.credentials_response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
            self.credentials_response['Credentials']['SessionToken'],
        )
        self.s3_client = get_s3_client(session=self.session)

    def _close(self):
        self.sts_client.close()
        self.s3_client.close()

def land_to_aws_s3(response, table_name, file_name):
    logger.info(
        f'{LOG_ENV_PREFIX}: \
         Landing json file into s3 bucket  ' +
        'table_name: \n:' + table_name,
    )
    json_bytes = BytesIO(json.dumps(response.json()['data']).encode('utf-8'))
    with S3Connection() as s3_connection:
        s3_response = s3_connection.s3_client.upload_fileobj(
            json_bytes,
            Bucket=LANDING_BUCKET,
            Key=LANDING_BUCKET_PATH + '/'+table_name+'/'+file_name,
            ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'application/json'},
        )
    return s3_response

Appreciate any advice or help as to the cause and fix. Driving us crazy.
We have certifi and openssl installed. We've tried running python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())" to ensure certificates exist in those paths. We've set SSL_CERT_FILE and REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE as env vars that have the paths to the certificates. We've tried multiple different python base images. Same error.

#1 Are  you behind a corporate proxy? #2 Try locally with docker and share the result. #3 Sometimes virtual machines born with rare issues or  it becomes unstable after manual and hot modifications. Delete the ec2 and try again

You need to install the root certificates for your docker image.  It's not unusual for them to ship without them.  Tell us what your upstream image is and we can help figure out how to install them
